# Adding a new field to all existing documents in an index?

Tags: lucene, luke

I am using Luke, to add a new field to all existing documents in the index. I can easily do this for 1 document by using the "Reconstruct and Edit" option. However, I want to do this for all document, in one go. Right now, I have to do this one by one. There are 2000 Documents in the index. This would take a lot of time.

Comment: Try using MatchAllDocsQuery to get all the documents and update them with new field

Comment: Interesting case, filed: https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke/issues/66  Any chance to use atomic update with solr, for instance?